# How to execute a method on every objects of a queryset in Django and return a list?

Tags: python, django

I have a ForeignKey relation between two models and I would like to execute a method on all objects and return the result in a list (or on every objects of a queryset). How can I do that?

For example:

```
status = Market.objects.all().is_update()
print(status)
[True, False, True]
if all(status):
    pass
```

This is how my models look like:

```
class Exchange(models.Model):
    pass

class Market(models.Model):
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='market', null=True)
    update = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=None)

    def is_update(self):
        # do stuff
        return True  # or return False
```

And this is how I do actually, but there must be a single line solution:

```
upd = []
for market in Market.objects.all():
    upd.append(market.is_update())
```

Thank you

Comment: `[market.is_update() for market in Market.objects.all()]`?

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh, how could I not think of that